# Assigning task property to variable

Tags: variables, properties, ssis, task

In SSIS, How do I assign to a user variable the value of a task property? I have a variable user::MinSimilarity and I want to assign to this the value of the MinSimilarity property of a Fuzzy Lookup task.

Answer (score 1):

Components, the things in Data Flow Tasks, use expressions differently than what you experience Tasks at the Control Flow level.

Generally, you don't have an Expressions collection available to you on the component. Instead, once you add a Component to a Data Flow, you then navigate back to the Control Flow itself, select the Data Flow's properties and *then* in the Data Flow's Expression collection, you can apply expressions for the objects within the data flow task.

[image]

It looks like the only property that surfaces for an expression on the Fuzzy Lookup is the `MaxMemoryUsage`. That *could* be because I don't have it properly configured but I suspect even if it were configured, this would be the only item available to me.

Getting to the properties menu

[image]

Comment: From where did that image of a Property Expressions Editor come?

Comment: @ThomasGabriel Updated to address